# Unable to start mysqld due to inability to allocate memory

Tags: mysql, innodb, ulimit

I'm unable to start mysqld due to it being unable to allocate enough memory.

I've installed the DB using the defaults:

`sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql`

Then when I try to start mysqld, I get this:

`name@host:/var/lib/mysql$ sudo mysqld --user=mysql`
`110307 16:01:21  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 2097168384 bytes of`
`InnoDB: memory with malloc! Total allocated memory`
`InnoDB: by InnoDB 35494096 bytes. Operating system errno: 12`
`InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or`
`InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.`
`InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with`
`InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.`
`InnoDB: Note that in most 32-bit computers the process`
`InnoDB: memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.`
`InnoDB: We keep retrying the allocation for 60 seconds...`
`InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool`
`110307 16:02:21 [ERROR] Default storage engine (InnoDB) is not available`
`110307 16:02:21 [ERROR] Aborting`

I haven't been able to find a way to increase ulimits though.  The box has enough memory to mysql, so I assume it's just a problem with the mysql user?

I'm using a Xen VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess from the error message and that since `2097168384` is suspiciously close to 2^31 you are running on a 32-bit system. Try reducing the amount of memory used by InnoDB in my.cnf, particularily `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and see if that allows MySQL to start.

See also the warning towards the bottom on the [MySQL InnoDB Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html) page about exceeding 2GB.